# Search Multiple ID's with Multiple Rows by Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have one table which is used to get data combination of input data.like multiple molecule(chemical combination) as one combination.

***Input***

```
$id = $required->input('search'); // array:2 [ 0 => "3" 1 => "8"]
```

***Case 1:***

***Table 1***

| id | refid | product_id | name | ref_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,3,46,7 | 5 | test | 6 |
| 2 | 1,3,8,90 | 10 | test1 | 8 |
| 3 | 3,8,67 | 14 | test 4 | 11 |
| 4 | 8,699, | 19 | test 4 | 11 |

***query***

```
$model=Model::whereIn('ref_id',$id)->pluck('product_id');
```

Fetch Product, query of combination contains id's ***3,8***

but it is fetching id's contains ***3 or 8***

***Case 2***

***Table 2***

| id | refid | product_id | name | ref_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | test | 6 |
| 2 | 5 | 10 | test1 | 8 |
| 3 | 8 | 5 | test 4 | 11 |
| 4 | 6 | 19 | test 4 | 11 |

```
$model = Model::whereIn('ref_id', $id)->groupBy('product_id')->pluck('product_id');
```

Is this possible to do and is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

`whereIn` does not work like that, it generates a query with `IN` operator.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (value1, value2)
```

You can simply use a `LIKE` operator to search `ref_id` column.

```php
$id = $required->input('search'); // array:2 [ 0 => "3" 1 => "8"]

$like = implode(',', $id); // string: "3,8"

$molecule = Molecule::where('ref_id', 'LIKE', "%{$like}%")->pluck('product_id');
```

Comment: hey thanks, i have another issue.could please elaborate the case 2 @Ozan kurt

Comment: It's a bit weird, in your example the `product_id` column in the database will be overwritten by your `GROUP BY` clause. I don't understand your logic there.

Comment: it is liek SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (value1, value2) group by product_id.

Comment: Yes I know, but it doesn't make sense, since it causes you to lose data. For example, the 1st rows name is "test" but it will be merged with the 3rd row. Which will cause the 3rd rows name "test 4" to be overwritten.
----
In the end you will be receiving: https://i.imgur.com/p300tJt.png

Comment: yes but there  is a catch,The product id will be same so it cannot be overwritten. i think,  the ref_id will be requested multiple id's. if the ref_id 3,8 has product_id  as 5.so it can be grouped.

Comment: @RubanS IMO, you cannot achieve what you want with this database structure. By moving `id` and `ref_id` to a different intermediate table, you can get (use a `join`) what you want.